# Where is the best place to get descriptions of malware?

Tags: malware, research

I'm looking for a source of descriptions of 1990s to early 2000s malware; I have searched for a very long time yet found very little. I require information such as payload activation dates, files created, files deleted, and similar.

Edit: I've found a few sites that give vague descriptions, such as the following:

https://www.symantec.com/security_response/landing/azlisting.jsp?azid=W - has many malicious programs listed, and gives descriptions of a few, but they aren't enough to determine payloads or activation dates.

https://www.f-secure.com/en/web/labs_global/threat-descriptions - only has recent malware.

http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/Threats.aspx - has a very large number of malware programs listed, but almost all have extremely generic descriptions

In addition, I found one source that was closer to what I wanted, but it had descriptions for only a very small number of programs: http://www.viriipedia.com/index.php?CN=20&CIE=1

Where does one find this type of historical data?

Comment: you mean like exploit-db.com? https://www.exploit-db.com/dos/?order_by=date&order=asc&pg=1

Comment: If you can get a hold of the samples you can submit them to malwr.com and get that information

Comment: Welcome. You are looking for a product recommendation (website), but that is [**off-topic**](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question.

Comment: @begueradj from a research perspective, I would allow this question (being specific to old malware) - but without further information about what he already found, I'm closing this as "unclear".

Comment: I've edited the post so as to be more specific. Thank you. exploit-db isn't very useful for me; I'm looking more for descriptions of actual malware programs than just exploits.

Comment: There are a lot of wiki's kicking about with articles about malware, they generally explain the malwares workings, its history and notable examples of that particular malware. The links below both including the history of malware dating back to its inception and continuing throughout the 90's 2000's and up to the present day. Being wiki's you may want to source and fact check any information contained within them though.

http://virus.wikidot.com/

and

http://malware.wikia.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try these links:

1. [Timeline of computer viruses and worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_computer_viruses_and_worms)
2. [Timeline of computer security hacker history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_computer_security_hacker_history)
3. [Securelist - Descriptions](https://securelist.com/description/)
4. [View Recent Malware](http://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/malware/latest.aspx)